# Angular:9 How to change variable from another sibling component?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a problem with updating string variable in Component1 where I change the value in Component2.

Components are independent of each other. Value in HTML template of Component1 doesn't update itself.

Is there a way to force template update? Beside that I tried: subscribe, @Input/@Output - but I might did that in wrong way.  Beside that, I think that I can't include selector in template (comp2) because it would display html template from component2  in component1. 
I hope I'm wrong. Please, lead me out of my mistake.

illustrative image:
[image: illustrative image]

Comment: You both had right. Article helped me a lot ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. If it's not a parent-child relationship between the components, then no point of looking at `@Input`.

If it's just the data that needs to be displayed in the sibling component, then use a service and bind in html. Look at this blog post: https://medium.com/@nodexperts_88267/data-transfer-one-component-to-another-angular-7-c076272c78e1

But if you also need to do something based on the change, then `BehaviorSubject` is way to go (Soham's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Behavior Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject).

```
// RxJS v6+
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);

// two new subscribers will get initial value => output: 123, 123
subject.subscribe(console.log);
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// two subscribers will get new value => output: 456, 456
subject.next(456);

// new subscriber will get latest value (456) => output: 456
subject.subscribe(console.log);

// all three subscribers will get new value => output: 789, 789, 789
subject.next(789);

// output: 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789, 789, 789
```